# Creating 2d array and generating 'x' character into array

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm writing a piece of code that allows the user to create a 2d array, then is printed as rows and columns of '0's. I then want to generate random 'x's into the array, but I have no idea how to do that section?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>

practice()
{
    //dynamically create an integer array of 2000 elements


    int size = 400;

    int i, j;
    // Function declarations 

    int* createArray(int rows, int cols); 
    void printArray(int *array, int rows, int cols); 
    void randomiseArray(int *array, int rows, int cols); 

    /* Exercise 5 function */ 


    { 
        int rows, cols; 

        //Get dimensions from user 

        printf("\nEnter rows and columns : "); 
        scanf("%d %d", &rows, &cols); 

        //Create array 

        int *myArray = createArray(rows, cols); 
        myArray = (int*) malloc(size * sizeof(int));
        printf("\nCreating array with dimensions [%d,%d] \n", rows, cols);
        //print, modify, print array 

        printArray(myArray, rows, cols); 
        for (i = 0; i < rows; i++)
        {
            for (j = 0; j < cols; j++)
            {
                //*myArray[i][j] = 0;   
                printf("%d",0);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
        printf("\n>array of size [%d][%d] created \n", rows, cols);
        return 0;

        randomiseArray(myArray, rows, cols); 
        printArray(myArray, rows, cols); 

        //free up space 

        free(myArray); 
    } 

    /* dynamically creates an array of size rows * cols, returns a pointer to the array */ 
    int* createArray(int rows, int cols) 
    { 
        int *temp; 
        return temp; 
    } 

    /* takes array and dimensions, prints out the contents formatted by row and column */      
    void printArray(int* array, int rows, int cols) 
    { 

    } 


    /* takes array and dimensions, randomly allocates 1-9 to each element */      
    void randomiseArray(int *array, int rows, int cols) 
    { 


    }
}
```

Comment: Take a look at `rand()`, or if you want more reliable functions at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random.

Comment: would i have to add another int to the 'int* createArray( int rows, int cols);'?

Comment: and use something like this- for(i=0; i<rows; i++)
 {
         for(j=0; j<cols; j++)
         {
                 myArray[i][j] = 10;
         }
 }